# Adding a third camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

As my company has a special need of installing a third camera on a Windows Phone Mango, do you think this is possible to access to the camera using Mango's Camera API?

As far as I can see the PhotoCamera only has two constructures: PhotoCamera() and PhotoCamera(CameraType type). The "type" here can only Primary or FrontFacing so I guess we cannot do anything else here.

We don't get this issue on Android, as they have the interface of Camera.open(int cameraId), and the cameraId can be any id between 0 and Camera.getNumberOfCameras() - 1.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused, as there's no way to "install" another camera.  There is no USB host port on the device, nor is there any other harcware interface, so how would you connect the camera physically?

Even if you could connect physically, there's no way for anyone other than a phone OEM to create and install the drivers for said camera, so how would the OS enumerate it to the platform?

If you're an OEM, you've undoubtedly got a support channel directly with Microsoft where you could ask this, as no one outside that channel is going to have any idea.  If you're not an OEM, there's simply no way to add a camera or any other (non-bluetooth) peripheral to the phone.

Comment: we will contact with a phone OEM to create and install the drivers for the camera. But as you know, Microsoft will not change the interface for any WP7, because it is simply not Android. All the devices running WP7 is expected has the same software architecture and there is no exception. As they said they support the front camera and rear camera, and they are optional, then that is all they have, we just cannot do with the third camera.